# manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct

Tags: locale

When I `ssh` into an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04, I get this error:

```
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

I tried this but this didn't fix it:

```
sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.3.7",
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("C.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.3.7",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.3.7",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "C"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Comment: It's the `LC_CTYPE` value (`UTF-8`) which is incorrect. Do you log in from a macOS machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm logging in from a macOS machine.

Comment: Somehow you export some locale variables from your local machine. The best way is to stop doing that, but unfortunately I'm not able to tell you how. Possibly you can work around the problem by inserting the line `unset LC_CTYPE` in the `~/.profile` file.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks, this seems to fix it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please feel free to post the solution (aka workaround) as an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer one's own question :)

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to disable sending LC_* environment variables. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609371/how-do-not-pass-locale-through-ssh , these steps fits for MacOS ssh client :

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Find these settings:

```
Host *
      SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Change it to :

```
Host *
#      SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Save the file, then try connecting again.

Comment: This is the right solution.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE` should be empty by default. I don’t think a properly configured macOS should set this variable. If you see this environment variable I think people should check their macOS language configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207823/manpath-cant-set-the-locale-make-sure-lc-and-lang-are-correct#comment2027421_1207823) I'm able to use this workaround:

`unset LC_CTYPE` in `~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I want to build on the YudhiWidyatama answer.

```
Host * !host_to_omit1 !host_to_omit2
SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Would be the right answer. Disabling this policy for every host seems a bit too drastic.

Answer (score 0):

perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (**unset**),
LC_ALL = (**unset**)

For me work just exsport this two
$ export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
$ export LANG=C.UTF-8